# Build Multi Module project with Maven in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-reactor

we're using jenkins and i'm wondering if it's possible to build all my modules using maven in 1 Job, our project structure is like this:

```
Web
├── Server
│   ├── moduleA
│   │   └── pom.xml <--- Module A POM
│   ├── moduleB
│   │   └── pom.xml <--- Module B POM
│   └── moduleC
│        └── pom.xml <--- Module C POM      
│
|──  Client 
        ├── Pom.xml
```

The way we're working now is that we have a jenkins job for every module in Server and 1 jenkins job for client Side , is it possible to create only one job and build All the Client and Server modules ?

Comment: Yes.  Look into `<modules>` in the pom in your root project.

Comment: Does this mean i have to add POM.xml in my Web folder and lookup other poms ?

Comment: Yes.  Now do the homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a parent pom that will contain all modules , than Jenkins will build this parent pom.

another option is to trigger several MVN commands ( but the first option is much better)